# CSS fade-in background image

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm learning CSS and I want to make that on a hover on some text, the text disappears and there is a fade-in on an image. I've tested some things but it doesn't work the way I want to do it.

The text is a link  in a  and on the hover I set the background image. I could use an  in the  but I want the text to be in the middle of the  and it's already in a  with an absolute position.

Here's the HTML :

```html
<div class="header"> 
  <!--<ul>-->
  <div class="header_element">
    <a title="Home" href="page.php"> Home </a>
  </div>
```

And the CSS :

```css
    div.header_element {
      display: table-cell;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      height: 100%;
    }

    div.header_element:hover {
      background-position: center;
      background-image: url("hover.png");
      background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    }
```

Would appreciate if anyone could help me with this.

Comment: add text-indent property. check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would like to probably use opacity and fade-in effect.

```
div.header_element {
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
}

div.header_element:hover {
background-position: center;
background-image: url("http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-100x100-Rope.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

See the [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/kybernaut/enaedwyz/) if it's what you wanted.

Comment: Doesn't this assume the image loads before the animation starts (or ends)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do it exactly the way you want. To "fade in" you normally animate the opacity of a layer, but that applies to the whole layer not just the background image. But why don't you move the Image to another layer, like this:

```
 <div class="header_element">
    <div class="header_background"></div>
    <a title="Home" href="page.php"> Home </a>
 </div>
```

Also it might be better to load the image before the user hovers, bc then you will have a visible delay until the image is actually loaded.

The CSS might look like this (not tested though):

```
.header_background {
    transition: opacity 1s;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url("hover.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity: 0;
}

.header_element:hover > .header_background {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: I didn't test it deeply, but I guess there would be a problem, the text would not be on the center of the div. It would be separated.

Comment: no, why should it? Add some CSS to make it positioned absolutely:

`position: absolute;  top: 0;  width: 100%;  height: 100%; `

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following css to see if it works for you:

```
.header_element{
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
}

.header_element > a{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

.header_element:hover > a{
    opacity: 0;
}

.header_element:hover{
    background: url(http://dummyimage.com/60x28/000/fff);
}
```

you can see the test here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asturias/t3ucL686/)

Comment: Thanks, you got me a better solution than I had for the text disappearing, I mixed this with kybernaut's fade in and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have added `text-indent` property to your existing CSS. So when you hover the link the text will go off-screen(hide) and you will see only image.

```
.header_element {
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 100%;
}

.header_element a:hover{
background-position: center;
background-image: url("http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-100x100-Rope.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;   
display:block;
text-indent: -9999px;   
}
```

http://jsbin.com/kexadaqaxu/3/edit

Comment: That was a good idea thanks, but the text was a link <a> so I guess I wasn't really clear in my explanations but I wanted to be still clickable. I just added a hover on the a which makes the text transparent and the text is big enough to not really see that you can still see it if you're not on it.

Comment: EDIT : asturnick's got a better solution, just use header_element:hover > a{ opacity: 0; } which hides the text even if not on it.